# How to handle visibility of a Text in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have this Text:

```
Text(
    text = stringResource(id = R.string.hello)
)
```

How can I show and hide this component?

I'm using Jetpack Compose version **'1.0.0-alpha03'**

Comment: "How can I show and hide this component?" -- wrap that function call in an `if` block that either does or does not call it. Remember: Compose is a functional reactive UI framework. You code is called each time that a change is needed. So, your code will be called for both the "show" and "hide" scenarios, and you need logic in that function to handle both cases.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

As CommonsWare stated, compose being a declarative toolkit you tie your component to a state (for ex: `isVisible`), then compose will intelligently decide which composables depend on that state and recompose them. For ex:

```
@Composable
fun MyText(isVisible: Boolean){
  if(isVisible){
     Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.hello))
  }
}
```

Also you could use the `AnimatedVisibility()` composable for animations.

Comment: This is a good answer. But what about if I need an element to occupy its bounds but not being visible? We used to have View.VISIBLE, View.INVISIBLE and View.GONE. Using an if it's just implementing GONE and VISIBLE

Comment: @SomerandomITboy then I'd probably move my if inside the modifier, something similar like `Modifier.opacity(if(isVisible) 1f else 0f)`

Comment: I didn't know about that modifier. Thanks!

Comment: On 1.0.0-beta04 try using 
```Modifier.alpha(if(isVisible) 1f else 0f)```

Comment: This is Create the Text only when the view is visible right?. Is there any way in which first we could create the view and then control its visibility?

Comment: @David normally you don't need to do that, because the visibility or not is a "state" that you recompose for.  However, in my case, i'm working a component inside a constraint layout and i dont want the anchor to go away, just not be seen (and changing opacity is a hack)

Answer (score 48):

You can simply add a condition like:

```
  if(isVisible){
     Text("....")
  }
```

Something like:

```
var visible by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
Column() {
    if (visible) {
        Text("Text")
    }
    Button(onClick = { visible = !visible }) { Text("Toggle") }
}
```

If you want to animate the appearance and disappearance of its content you can use the [**`AnimatedVisibility`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#animatedvisibility)

```
var visible by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
Column() {
    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = visible,
        enter = fadeIn(
            // Overwrites the initial value of alpha to 0.4f for fade in, 0 by default
            initialAlpha = 0.4f
        ),
        exit = fadeOut(
            // Overwrites the default animation with tween
            animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 250)
        )
    ) {
        // Content that needs to appear/disappear goes here:
        Text("....")
    }
    Button(onClick = { visible = !visible }) { Text("Toggle") }
}
```

Comment: This is Create the Text only when the view is visible right?. Is there any way in which first we could create the view and then control its visibility?

Answer (score 13):

As stated above, you could use AnimatedVisibility like:

```
AnimatedVisibility(visible = yourCondition) { Text(text = getString(R.string.yourString)) }
```

Comment: This is Create the Text only when the view is visible right?. Is there any way in which first we could create the view and then control its visibility?

Answer (score 3):

```kotlin
/**
 * @param visible if false content is invisible ie. space is still occupied
 */
@Composable
fun Visibility(
    visible: Boolean,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val contentSize = remember { mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero) }

    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .onSizeChanged { size -> contentSize.value = size }) {
        if (visible || contentSize.value == IntSize.Zero) {
            content()
        } else {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(contentSize.value.width.pxToDp(), contentSize.value.height.pxToDp()))
        }
    }
}


fun Int.pxToDp(): Dp {
    return (this / getSystem().displayMetrics.density).dp
}
```

usage:

```kotlin
Visibility(text.value.isNotEmpty()) {
    IconButton(
        onClick = { text.value = "" },
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(bottom = 8.dp)
            .height(30.dp),
    ) {
        Icon(Icons.Filled.Close, contentDescription = "Clear text")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just and alternative using the solutions proposed Creating an Enum with a remember value :

```
var visible by remember { mutableStateOf(Visibility.VISIBLE) }
```

Here is the full code:

```
enum class Visibility {
    VISIBLE,
    INVISIBLE,
    GONE,
}



  @Composable
fun MyTextWithVisibilityAndOpacity(visibility: Visibility) {
    if (visibility == Visibility.VISIBLE) {
        Text(
            text = "Hello, Jetpack Compose!",
            color = Color.Black,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
                .opacity(if (visibility == Visibility.INVISIBLE) 0f else 1f)
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyApp() {
    var visible by remember { mutableStateOf(Visibility.VISIBLE) }

    Column {
        MyTextWithVisibilityAndOpacity(visible)
        Button(onClick = {
            visible = when (Random.nextInt(3)) {
                0 -> Visibility.VISIBLE
                1 -> Visibility.INVISIBLE
                else -> Visibility.GONE
            }
        }) {
            Text(text = "Toggle Visibility")
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewApp() {
    MyApp()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `animateFloatAsState` Composable.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun AnimationExample(loading: Boolean) {
    val alpha: Float by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = if (loading) 1f else 0f,
        animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = 300,
            easing = LinearEasing,
        ),
        label = "alpha"
    )
    Text(
        text = stringResource(id = R.string.hello),
        modifier = Modifier.alpha(alpha),
    )
}
```